Is the modern formulation of Pappus's notion of Cross-ratio of Gaussian origin?
According to Wikipedia, the Cross-ratio is a key notion of modern geometry, which enabled after a long evolutionary process, to devlope a calculus of distances in different models of the hyperbolic plane (read Cayley–Klein metric), among other things. This notion was originally defined by Pappus of Alexandria as a real number associated with a list of four collinear points.
Modern use of the Cross-ratio began with Lazare Carnot in 1803 in his book Géométrie de Position, who proved several interesting facts about it, thereby sharpening Pappus's concept. According to Wikipedia, this approach to geometry was used by Karl von Staudt four decades later (in 1847) to set a new foundation to geometry.
However, I did not succeed in finding out who was the first to treat the four points as complex numbers (like in the modern contexts, with its key invariance property under Mobius transformations). As someone who spent a huge amount of hours digging into Gauss's writings, I found the following remark of Paul Stackel on several Gaussian writings on the application of complex numbers to geometry:

Around 1840 Gauss generalized the concept of harmonic pairs of points on a straight line by considering the four abscissas as complex quantities to which points of a plane are assigned (W. VIII, pp. 336—337). This is a fruitful transfer principle which Möbius, here again after meeting Gauss, developed. Later Möbius moved on to the general double relationship and arrived at his theory of circle affinity, in which a relationship is established between two planes by a bilinear equation in the complex quantities determining their position.

Stackel refers to pp. 335-338 of volume 8 of Gauss's Werke, which are entitled "The circle" and are included in a part of this volume dealing "applications of complex numbers to geometry". In these passages, Gauss gives some expressions about circles and harmonic pairs of points which resemble Cross-ratios, and in [II] (entitled "Circle through four points") he gives the following conditional equation for four points to lie on a circle:

The conditional equation that four points $0,a,b,c$ whose complex conjugates are $0,A,B,C$ all lie in a circle is: ... $$c(a-b)B(A-C) = b(a-c)C(A-B)$$

Since the fourth point is $0$ (the origin), one can reformulate this condition as: $$(c-0)(a-b)(B-0)(A-C) = (b-0)(a-c)(C-0)(A-B)\implies \frac{(c-0)(a-b)}{(b-0)(a-c))}=\frac{(C-0)(A-B)}{(B-0)(A-C)}$$
Since $0,A,B,C$ are defined as $0,\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c}$, this condition amounts to the Cross-ratio of $0,a,b,c$ to be equal to its own complex conjugate - a real number. So Gauss's conditional equation states that four points lie on circle if their Cross-ratio is real (this fact is correct). Gauss also writes (in [3] of [II]):

The points which are reciprocal of three of those points in relation to the fourth lie in a straight line. This sentence is understood under the general: "All points which are reciprocal to the points of a circle with respect to a given point lie in one circle."

The four points mentioned here are the four cocyclic points in [2] of [II]; according to what I read, the reciprocal point to a complex point $z$ with respect to the origin is $\frac{1}{z}$ (a special case of Mobius transformation). So Gauss states that under reciprocation with respect to an arbitrary center $z_0$ (not just the origin) circles remain circles. His first sentence claims that for arbitrary three complex points, reciprocation with respect to a fourth point that lies on their common circle produces three collinear points.
Interestingly, Stackel also refers to an appendix written by Gauss in 1810 to Schumacher's german translation of Lazare Carnot 1803 treatise (the same treatise in which Carnot revived Pappus's concept), in which Gauss gave a series of original analytical demonstrations for some geometrical theorem included in this work (Stackel refers to p.397 of volume 4 of Gauss's Werke). There are also other indications that Gauss understood the importance of the cross-ratio: for example, he used the Cayley-Klein metric (which is related to the notion of cross-ratio) to calculate the sides of triangles in a tessellation of the unit disk.
Honestly, I have not done yet a serious study on the notion of Cross-ratio, so it might be possible that there are other authors before Gauss who developed it, so this is what I want to check. In the historical section in Wikipedia article, only von Staudt is mentioned after Lazare Carnot. If someone knows more about the history of this topic, I'll be glad if he will share the information!

See Gray, Poncelet, Chasles, and the Early Years of Projective Geometry:"The notion of cross-ratio was known to Brianchon, and is mentioned as such (without the name cross-ratio) in Poncelet’s Traite [1822]... In 1829... Chasles wrote a long essay arguing that the theory of projective geometry rests essentially on the notion of cross-ratio... his use of cross-ratio, developed at length in his Theorie de geometrie superieure (1852) with nothing more exotic than imaginary points." In German, Steiner developed it after 1822.

@Conifold -  Thanks for this source. Unfortunately I could only read freely the abstract and the first two pages of this chapter. It is useful to know that Poncelet, Chasles and Steiner also developed this notion in the period between Carnot and von Staudt. If you have access to this chapter/book, can you locate who was the first to formulate the cross-ratio as a relation between four complex numbers? there are good reasons to believe this was firstly done by Gauss. However,  if his notes were unpublished and nobody knew about them, then the answer to the title question of my post is no.

I don't know to what Stackel meant when he said: "This is a fruitful transfer principle which Möbius, here again meeting Gauss, developed.". Did Gauss share with Mobius some of his thoughts on the cross-ratio?

According to Fano (1907, p. 382), “the concept of cross-ratio of four points of a [Riemann] sphere goes back to Möbius” (1852 = 1856 = Werke II pp. 189-204).

@ConsigliereZARF - if Mobius was first to introduce the concept of complex cross-ratio in 1852, than Gauss definitely preceeded him (Gauss wrote the above fragments around 1840). What remains is to check if this was another useless anticipation of Gauss (i.e was unpublished, and had zero historic influence), or that Gauss somehow exerted direct or indirect influence. I could not find a report of a meeting of Mobius and Gauss around 1840, so I tend to believe that Mobius's work was independent.

Anyway, it is still nice to acquainte myself with another aspect of Gauss's geometric work. By the way, do you know what Gauss meant when he wrote about reciprocal points (in [3] of [II], I included the relevant remarks in my posted question)?

Chasles and Möbius introduced the complex version  independently around 1852, this is also mentioned by McTutor. Gauss, in his usual manner, did not publish, so it only spread through Möbius. Chasles arrived at it independently, he was not familiar with literature in German generally, not even with Steiner.
